# How to initialize a String with NSData with ARC

Tags: objective-c, ios, automatic-ref-counting

I'm trying to do this:

```
NSString *responseDataString = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:responseData encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

but in ARC, I can't use `[NSString alloc]`. I do not want to disable ARC for this file, so is there a way to do the same thing in ARC with other methods?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`alloc` works just fine under ARC. The code you've written should be OK. Why do you think it's not working?

Comment: Ah, you're right. I think I just had a typo, how silly of me.

Answer (score 1):

`[ NSString alloc ]` is perfectly valid under ARC.